# Obtain vector direction from shp file

Tags: c#, gis

I've started doing some research into gis applications using .shp files
I couldn't find any good source of documentation into this, but i'd really want to know if given a .shp (and its companion files) is there a way to know if the information stored in these files provides the direction of the vectors?
More to the point, i'm using a particular street map and i'd want to know how to check if my files provide me with the vectorial direction.

If its of any relevance i'm using SharpMap as my gis library but i'm open to suggestions in this front too

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The shape file format supports geometries of a number of different types, but for the case of your question I'm going to assume that we're talking about a shape file with multiline features.

The geometries stored have coordinates, depending on the type of projection/datum chosen by the author of the shape file, those coordinates could be simple {X,Y} pairs - or they could be  {X,Y,Z,M} - the information in each coordinate varies and there are a number of different schemes. Ok, so thats the value - but whats the 'value' of X and Y? Well that depends on which map projection the author of the shape file used when he created it. The shape file format, by itself, doesn't tell you what X and Y are measurements of, or what they mean. For example, in the popular WGS1984 projection X and Y are longitude and lattitude. However in the NAD1983 projection, those values represent distances from a known point on a local scale.

Shape files are more like maps (on paper), and the name shape file is an accurate moniker. It's basically a geometry information holder, and the actual information that composes those geometries can be different depending on the usage/intent of the shapes. A simple sidewalk construction prelim plan would most likely be a bunch of rectangles down the road (simple X,Y polygons), but an elevation contour map might have X,Y,Z,M information where Z would be elevation and M would be a stored measurement along the contour.

That being said, if you want vector information (i assume you mean geometric vectors) from the shape file - you should be fine to use the line segments as such so long as the coordinate system you are using jives with the info in the file and you are willing to work in the local map projection of the shape file (or reproject the geometries to the coordinate system you are using).

Comment: But, supose i take the line segments, i want to know what point is  the start of the line and which one is the end, so as to know de direction of the line (from right to left, or from left to right)